# How to sort CPT by custom meta value (date), and return posts month by month

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, metabox, date

**For future reference**: 
I am using the great [Meta Box Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/) to help expedite meta box creation for my custom post types.

**My goal**:  
To build a highly customizable events section closely resembling a traditional calendar like `get_calendar` creates, but for a specific custom post type.

**The Problem:**
— By relying solely on using Wordpresses built in [time parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters), I am able to return my posts in an ASC order similar to a traditional calendar but I am limited to only showing posts up to the current day since there is no way to query and return [scheduled posts](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/schedule-your-posts-in-wordpress/) - this is an issue obviously since I need to display ALL event posts for the current month, and onward...
— Additionally, I also need to be able to page to "previous" and "upcoming" months similar to `get_calendar`.

**My Solution Thus Far**:
— Due to the time parameter restrictions, I've opted to return my posts via `WP_Query`'s `meta_key` parameter instead and assigned it to my events "startdate" field, and then orderby - `meta_value_num`...

This seems to replicate the same functionality Im after for the most part but now I'm posed with a serious issue of:

> "how do i treat this meta value just like wordpresses native time parameters so that I can store this data appropriately for each month and have the option to page through the months similar to the get_calendar archive?"

Hopefully I was definitive enough in my explanation to help anyone who reads this make sense of it all. If not, please let me know and I will happily attempt to further clarify whatever it is...and thank you for the help!

---

Pasted below is my current "Calendar/Events" template as well as a screenshot of how it will most likely look on the front end.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Calendar
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- featured_images.php -->
<?php include ('featured_images.php'); ?>

    <div id="full_col">

        <h2 class="feed_title_full"><?php wp_title('', true); ?></h2>
        <div id="calendar_nav">
            <h4 id="current_month"><?php the_time( 'F Y' ); ?></h4>
        </div>

        <ul id="calendar">

            <?php $current_year = date('Y'); // Get current YEAR ?> 
            <?php $current_month = date('m'); // Get current MONTH ?>
            <?php $calandar_posts = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'calendar', 
                    'year' => $current_year,
                    'monthnum' => $current_month, // Show ALL posts for current Month 
                    'meta_key' => 'epr_startdate',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'ASC', 
                    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                )); 
            ?>
            <?php if($calandar_posts->have_posts()) : while($calandar_posts->have_posts()) : $calandar_posts->the_post(); ?>

                <li class="calendar_entry">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="calendar_link" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"></a>
                    <div class="entry_date">
                        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_startdate', TRUE); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shadow_overlay"></div>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('calendar-teaser', array('class' => 'calendar-teaser-img', 'alt' => 'View Event')); ?>
                </li>

            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <h2>No Events for the month of <?php the_time( 'F' ); ?></h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </ul>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: what is your desired single event permalink? what is your desired calendar archive page permalink? as far as querying by a date meta field is concerned, there are several examples on this site if you search around, start in the related column on this page.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I have my calendar post type set to rewrite like so: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event' )`, --- so basically a single event permalink would appear like: http://www.mysite.com/event/my-event-title.... As far as how the calendar archive permalink would be, Im not super picky as long as its achievable - but preferably something like: http://www.mysite.com/calendar/year/month. My page that the calendar post type is queried on is titled - "Calendar" for future reference.

Comment: you have the option to set `calendar` as your post type archive slug via `register_post_type`'s `has_archive` argument rather than use a separate page for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't complete copy/paste code, but hopefully it's understandable enough to get you started.

First step is to register your post type and add a rewrite rule to handle years/months. This will give you single events at `event/post-name/`, your post type archive at `calendar`, and handle incoming requests for `calendar/yyyy/mm/`. Make sure to visit your Settings > Permalinks page after this is added to flush the rewrite rules.

```
function wpa88173_calendar_post_type() {

    // just the important bits shown here
    $args = array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event' )
        'has_archive' => 'calendar',
    );

    register_post_type( 'calendar', $args );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^calendar/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?',
        'index.php?post_type=calendar&calendar_year=$matches[1]&calendar_month=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa88173_calendar_post_type' );
```

Next step is to add the `calendar_year` and `calendar_month` query vars so WordPress adds them to the array of query vars when the incoming requests are parsed.

```
function wpa88173_calendar_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'calendar_year';
    $query_vars[] = 'calendar_month';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa88173_calendar_query_vars' );
```

The next step is to add an action to `pre_get_posts`, which checks if it's the calendar post type archive, fetches the year/month or sets it to the current year/month, then modifies the query with `meta_query` parameters to load the requested year/month. See [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for more info on meta queries. This assumes a date format of `yyyymmdd`.

```
function wpa88173_calendar_query( $query ) {
    // is it a post type archive?
    if( ! $query->is_post_type_archive( 'calendar' ) )
        return;

    // is it the main query and not an admin page?      
    if( $query->is_main_query()
        && ! is_admin() ) {

        // check if year/month was set via the URI, or set it to current year/month
        ( ! empty( $query->query_vars['calendar_year'] ) ) ? $query_year = $query->query_vars['calendar_year'] : $query_year = date('Y');
        ( ! empty( $query->query_vars['calendar_month'] ) ) ? $query_month = $query->query_vars['calendar_month'] : $query_month = date('m');

        // meta_query parameters for events between start and end dates
        $date_start = $query_year . $query_month . '01';
        $date_end = $query_year . $query_month . '31';
        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'value' => array( $date_start, $date_end ),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        );

        // modify the query
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa88173_calendar_query' );
```

The last step will be for you to build the calendar in your template and create the next/previous links to page through months. You can get the queried year/month in the template via [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

**EDIT** - Here's an example of building the links with plain ol' math

```
( '' == get_query_var( 'calendar_month' ) ) ? $this_month = date( 'n' ) : $this_month = ltrim( get_query_var( 'calendar_month' ), '0' );
( '' == get_query_var( 'calendar_year' ) ) ? $this_year = date( 'Y' ) : $this_year = get_query_var( 'calendar_year' );

if( 1 == $this_month ):
    $next_month = 2;
    $prev_month = 12;
    $next_year = $this_year;
    $prev_year = $this_year - 1;
elseif( 12 == $this_month ):
    $next_month = 1;
    $prev_month = 11;
    $next_year = $this_year + 1;
    $prev_year = $this_year;
else:
    $next_month = $this_month + 1;
    $prev_month = $this_month - 1;
    $next_year = $this_year;
    $prev_year = $this_year;
endif;

$next_month = str_pad( $next_month , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
$prev_month = str_pad( $prev_month , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

echo 'next month: /calendar/' . $next_year . '/' . $next_month . '/';
echo 'previous month: /calendar/' . $prev_year . '/' . $prev_month . '/';
```

Comment: So adding the rewrite rule seems to cause the query to not return anything anymore, or even load the correct template for that matter...this is after flushing my permalinks as well. Not sure what Im missing.

Comment: in this example, `calendar` isn't a page, it's the post type archive, so the template would be `archive-calendar.php`, and the loop will be just the standard loop, no query within the template is necessary. also note the `has_archive` parameter of `register_post_type`. if you also have a page named `calendar`, it may produce strange results.

Comment: After trouble-shooting I believe thats exactly what the problem is, their sharing the same slug which Wordpress doesnt seem to care for apparently. I tried changing the `has_archive` parameter to `calendars` instead and I was immediately able to at least get my posts to return again so i suppose Ill just keep it plural to be on the safe side.

Comment: Is it not necessary to use `add_rewrite_tag` with `add_rewrite_rule` in this case?

Comment: Actually, the only part that doesnt seem to be working out for me thus far is the function that adds the `calendar_year` and `calendar_month` query vars.

Comment: if you change has_archive, you also need to change the rewrite rule to match. you don't need add_rewrite_tag, just adding the query vars is all that's necessary. if the query vars aren't being added (and I don't really see how that's possible), then the pre_get_posts action won't work at all. all of this works as-is pasted into the twenty eleven theme, if it's not working for you, you probably have naming issues somewhere- you've changed the name of one thing, but not something else and broken things. I'm not sure why you even need a page named `calendar` if this essentially takes its place.

Comment: Your right Milo, I deleted the calendar page after you mentioned that this is all working directly in the `archive-calendar.php` template now. I will have to scan through it all this evening to see what I missed. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Still no dice unfortunately. I updated my original question with an edit to show what I have. - Could there be a post type param that I need to enable/disable in order for the rewrite and pre_get_posts to work?

Comment: ahh, sorry, my fault, you're right about the query vars thing, I had changed the name of the variable to make it more descriptive when I pasted it here and missed one instance of it - `return $qvars` should be `return $query_vars`. also I've realized that the meta query should be `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` instead of `'type' => 'DATE'`, since I've cheated a bit with the last day of the month, setting it to `31`, however MySQL doesn't like this when the month doesn't actually have 31 days in it! You can also fix it by using PHP's date `t` to get the number of days in a given month.

Comment: OK, I'm actually able to return the calendar posts now with the `return $query_vars` fix but as soon as I change `type =>` to `NUMERIC` nothing is returned anymore.

Comment: make sure the date format you're storing matches what the query is passing. numeric won't work with non-numeric separator characters in the date. the other option as I mentioned is to get the actual number of days in the month and leave it as a date comparison, though you may also need to change the orderby to meta_value instead of meta_value_num

Comment: Not sure how to approach using `get_query_var` to produce the prev/next month links, do I need to assign an arbitrary variable to get_query_var first? Only example I see in the codex is for the traditional paging.

Comment: get_query_var will give you the current value of calendar_year and calendar_month from the URL (ex: `get_query_var( 'calendar_year' )`), or if they are not set then you know the value should be this year and month. you can then build links to next and previous months by adding or subtracting a month. see php's date, strtotime, and mktime for doing date calculations.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I actually tried the exact example you just gave previously assuming that may work since that was one of the new query_vars you assigned in your function though I don't understand how the maths supposed to work in order to build the links :( Apologies.

Comment: if the current year is 2013 and month is 02, the link to the previous calendar will be `/calendar/2013/01/`, the link to the next calendar will be `/calendar/2013/03/`, you're just adding or subtracting a month. the only case you need to look out for is when the month is 1 or 12, then you have to also change the year.

Comment: I checked off your answer Milo, thanks again for the help (it really does mean a lot). I still have been unable to sort out retrieving the correct prev/next month links for the paging bit unfortunately however so if you have any examples you might be able to share it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dunno if its the correct approach - but I followed the directions you gave to a similar question HERE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39679/using-strtotime-function-to-convert-a-custom-meta-box-to-a-date-stamp, and as far as I can tell it seems to return the correct month for displaying the associated month to the current posts being viewed. One caveat I noticed is that if I got to a month that has no posts then the date is not returned correctly and outputs as January 1970 instead. Now just gotta sort out the links I guess.

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: Milo your a lifesaver, I think I get the gist of what you did in terms of the math but the scope of the php you wrote to accomplish this was a tad over my head in some areas so thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Hi Milo , I have the very same problem and whenever i try to get `my-cpt-name/2015`  it matches `post_type=my-cpt-name&year=$matches[1] ` while my Rewrite rule `post_type=my-cpt-name&donation_year=$matches[1]` comes only second . Can you please guide me on what went wrong  ?