# Formatting custom meta box date from YYYY/MM/DD to a more readable alternative

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, date-time, post-meta

### QUESTION

This is following a previous question that was graciously answered by Milo earlier here - [How to sort CPT by custom meta value (date), and return posts month by month](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88173/how-to-sort-cpt-by-custom-meta-value-date-and-return-posts-month-by-month)

In short, I'm having some issues with properly formatting my custom meta box date's in a few areas... Namely, in the back-end in my custom columns, and then in the front-end in my archive template.

For example, in my archive template I'm trying to return the current date that the posts belong to via the code pasted below, but when I visit a month with no posts my template returns the date "January 1970" instead.

```
<?php $calendar_month = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_startdate', TRUE);?>
<?php $this_month = strtotime($calendar_month); ?>
<span id="current_month"><?php echo date( 'F Y', $this_month ); ?></span>
```

Additionally, in the back-end I'm trying to have it so that if just the "start date" is created then ONLY output that information, whereas, if the user enters both a "start date" and an "end date" then retun both dates, but when I use the code example below my start dates are returned in duplicate like this instead: Mar 3, 2013 — Mar 3, 2013.

```
case "eventdate":
                $eventstart = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_startdate', true);
                $eventstart_col = strtotime($eventstart);

                $eventend = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_enddate', true);
                $eventend_col = strtotime($eventend);

                if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_startdate', true) && ! get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_enddate', true) )
                    echo date( 'M n, Y', $eventstart_col );
                elseif ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_enddate', true) )
                    echo date( 'M n, Y', $eventstart_col ) . ' &mdash; ' . date( 'M n, Y', $eventend_col );
                else
                    echo 'NA';
                break;
```

Thank you in advance for your time.
Best

---

### FINAL SOLUTION

Big thank you to [s_ha_dum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum) for his patience and support!
Pasted below are the final working solutions to my question...

**Correctly outputting the date when no posts exist for the currently queried month:**

```
<?php $this_month = strtotime($calendar_month);
if (false === $this_month) {
$this_month = strtotime(get_query_var( 'calendar_year' ) . get_query_var( 'calendar_month' ) .'01');
} ?>
<span id="current_month"><?php echo date( 'F Y', $this_month ); ?></span><?php
?>
```

**Custom columns:**

```
case "eventdate":
                $start_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_startdate', true);
                $start_date_col = strtotime($start_date);           
                $end_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_enddate', true);
                $end_date_col = strtotime($end_date);
                
                if ( $start_date_col && !$end_date_col ) 
                    echo date( 'M d, Y', $start_date_col );
                elseif ( $start_date_col && $end_date_col )
                    echo date( 'M d, Y', $start_date_col ) . ' &mdash; ' . date( 'M d, Y', $end_date_col );  
                else
                    echo 'NA';
                break;
```

**Redirecting /calendar -> /calendar/yyyy/mm:**

```
function redirect_empty_archive() {
$m = get_query_var('calendar_month');
$y = get_query_var('calendar_year');
    if (
        is_post_type_archive('calendar') &&
        ( empty($m) || empty($y) )
    ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( '/calendar' . date('/Y/m') );
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_empty_archive');
```

Comment: To get an answer your going to have to make the question shorter, just show some simple examples of what you get compared to what you're expecting.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was worried too little would not be enough hence the long post. I will shorten it.

Comment: I've truncated my question to only show the most important information now. Thanks.

Comment: As regards the second part - are you sure you are saving the start and end dates correctly? You are not saving the start date into both fields?

Comment: I believe they are being saved correctly, yes. They are being stored via a date and time picker from the meta box plugin in yyyy/mm/dd format which is why I'm attempting to use `strtotime` to change the format on the front end. The user has the option to enter just a start date, or both.

Comment: Anyone else have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I visit a month with no posts my template returns the date
>   "January 1970" instead.

Yes. That will happen. UNIXTIME began on Jan 1, 1970. That is "0000/00/00" but negative numbers work back until sometime in 1901. `strtotime` will return `false` for anything outside that range, including your nonexistent dates. `date` will assume "day zero" if given a bad date, hence you get Jan 1, 1970 for nonexistent or otherwise flawed dates. 64 bit machines can handle larger ranges, if I remember correctly. Either way a nonexistent date will give you 1970. Try:

```
$calendar_month = "1901/01/01";
$this_month = strtotime($calendar_month);
var_dump($this_month);
echo '<br />';
echo date('Y',$this_month);
echo '<br />';
```

You want to make sure you have a good date before displaying it.

```
<?php $this_month = strtotime($calendar_month); 
if (false !== $this_month) { ?>
  <span id="current_month"><?php echo date( 'F Y', $this_month ); ?></span><?php
}
```

Your other code is a little bulky, but looks like it should work except that your date format is wrong. You aren't getting "Month Day, Year" as I suspect you want but "Month-Name Month-Number, Year", which will look like a duplicate if the two dates are in the same month/year. Take a good look at the [date formatting operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$eventstart = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_startdate', true);
$eventstart_col = strtotime($eventstart);

$eventend = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epr_enddate', true);
$eventend_col = strtotime($eventend);

if ( $eventstart_col && !$eventend_col ) {
    // only the start date
    echo date( 'M d, Y', $eventstart_col );
} elseif ( $eventstart_col && $eventend_col ) {
    // both start and end date
    echo date( 'M d, Y', $eventstart_col ) . ' &mdash; ' . date( 'M d, Y', $eventend_col );  
} else {
    echo 'NA';
}
```

I think I have that put back together correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'm out of town right now but when I get back in I will give this a go and report back. Really appreciate the response, thank you!

Comment: The custom columns fix works excellent, thank you! The first part of your code only produced January 1901 for me however.

Comment: The first part of my code would produce January 1901, as that is the date I hard-coded. That was illustrative. You aren't supposed to use that code for anything other than just proof of concept. If you are on a 32 bit machine that should return `false`. On a 64 bit it probably gives you the right date. I assume you are on a 64 bit machine. If you want to get `false` on a 64 bit machine just mess with the date. You will eventually get there but I don't know (without looking it up) exactly where that mark is. Use `null` or a very old date like "1000/01/01", or an empty string instead of a date.

Comment: Doh! Sorry I missed that. Ok, well assuming Im doing this right, using an empty string returns nothing. Does it make a difference that this date is coming from a jquery date picker?

Comment: No. Datepicker isn't a factor. The date is a string like any other.

Comment: OK, i think I must have clearly missed your point. Ive updated my original question to illustrate.

Comment: `strtotime` will return `false` for an empty string (yes, you understand what I mean by empty string) but you won't see it unless you use `var_dump`. `date` will assume day zero and return information for "January 1, 1970". I don't understand what is still not working.

Comment: Well the only way Im even able to produce an accurate date, as long as there are posts existing in a particular month is if I use `get_post_meta` like I was previously...by using your illustrative example, `int(-2177452800)<br>1901<br>` is whats returned...by using your suggested example below that, nothing is returned. I assume Im just missing something very simple, but not sure what.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7949/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-mr-brown)